How to get Google access token without selecting Google account again using @abacritt/angularx-social-login
I am using the library @abacritt/angularx-social-login to implement Google authentication for my Angular 17 application. When I do sign in with Google, the application ask me to select Google account for once, but then when I do request for Google access token (like the example in the library document), the application ask me to select Google account AGAIN, even though I have already been logged in.
Is there any way to make it not ask to select Google account (when requesting for Google access token) if I'm already logged in?

It looks like the library @abacritt/angularx-social-login wraps Google Identity Services SDK token model. My best guess is here. For what you wanted to do, you can use the parameters prompt='' and login_hint=XXXXX in TokenClientConfig. However, I don't see @abacritt/angularx-social-login exposes these two parameters for callers like you to set. You may want to contact the owners of the plugin to put in the feature request.
